# Горячие клавиши в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, fedora, kde

Использую fedora 22 (kde5) и PhpStorm9. Проблема в том что все горячие клавиши из шторма перехватываются глобальными из KDE.

Например, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> вместо форматирования кода блокирует систему.

Можно ли как-то это исправить оставив горячие клавиши kde?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы касательно PhpStorm необходимо задавать компании производителю. Тем-более, что support в JetBrains на высшем уровне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переназначить клавиши PHPStorm. Я, например, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> перенёс на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>. :) Комбинации настраиваются File->Settings->Keymaps в PHPStorm'е.

Comment: Я никогда не смогу себя переучить -_-

Comment: Ну блокировка экрана это глобальная комбинация в любой системе. Значит, меняйте глобальную комбинацию блокировки экрана, что бы не было конфликта. :)